# Como trazer dados de um webservice JSON no Android

Tags: php, java, android

Queria que alguém me explicasse como fazer isso..Tenho o seguinte código em PHP e queria trazer para o Android, retornando o nome da pessoa. Pode ser em um Array...O problema é que eu não consigo pegar estes dados.

```php
$f = fopen('POST_DATA.txt', 'a');
fwrite($f, 'ID: '.$id."\r\n");
$id = uniqid( time() );
fwrite($f, 'Nome: '.$_POST['nome']."\r\n");
fwrite($f, 'Cpf: '.$_POST['cpf']."\r\n");
fwrite($f, 'Bairro: '.$_POST['bairro']."\r\n");
fwrite($f, 'E-mail: '.$_POST['email']."\r\n");
fwrite($f, 'Telefone: '.$_POST['telefone']."\r\n\r\n");

fclose($f);

echo 'Dados enviados com sucesso';
```

Comment: Não entendi sua pergunta. Poderia reformular?

Comment: Creio que a outra pergunta sua está melhor. Apague esta se a dúvida é mesma que http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/69364/como-retornar-dados-com-json

Comment: Sim, mas aquela pergunta não responde o que eu quero saber. Gostaria de pegar estes dados e mostrar eles no android. Tenho uma aplicação que precisa saber qual usuário está logado. Precisaria pegar o nome com o JSON e verificar se é o usuário está logado ou não. Só não consigo pegar estes dados do PHP